# Adding TimeStamps with EF 4.3 Migrations

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Code First Migrations and I'm altering my model to add timestamp fields to my tables. I'm trying to add the timetamp fields in my second migration. Here is a sample of what my code looks like

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }      
    public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

 public class UserModelConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<User> {
        public UserModelConfiguration() {
            Property(p => p.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250);
            Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();            
        }
    }
```

The generated migration looks like this

```
public override void Up()
        {                
            AddColumn("Users", "TimeStamp", c => c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"));
        }
```

When I execute the Update-Database command, I get an error message that says  **"Defaults cannot be created on columns of data type timestamp. Table 'Users', column 'TimeStamp'.
Could not create constraint**" I moved all the data from the table, but that didn't solve the issue.

How can I go about adding a timestamp field to this migration set?

Comment: Try nullable:true. The timestamps will be filled anyway.

Comment: That worked. Generate the right SQL when you apply the -Script directive. Add your answer and so I can mark this solved

Comment: Was the script generated using a Timestamp/Rowversion data type or byte()?

Comment: generated as timestamp not null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `nullable:true`. The timestamp column will have `null` in the column specification but it will be filled anyway.

Comment: Oddly enough... my generated schema shows the timestamp field as not null. I don't know if this behavior depends on what version of SQL Server is used

Comment: I ran your code successfully on SQL Server 2008 R2 (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)). What version are you running it on Cecil?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 x64 - 10.0.4064.0

Answer (score 0):

We just came across this exact problem today.  Our solution was to delete the table then to recreate it all via migrations.  2 separate migration scripts.

Obviously not ideal if you want to retain the data but, in our case, this was not an issue.

Would be interesting to hear about a less kludgy solution.

HTH.

Comment: I did try that too. I does feel like a dirty solution. I submitted feedback to the EF UserVoice http://goo.gl/ByCs. I just waiting for it to be approved

Answer (score 0):

FYI this bug was fixed in EF 5.0 beta 2. The best workaround for previous versions is what was already mentioned here: specify nullable:true. Thanks for reporting the issue!